# How To Correct My Preg match fuction in php

Tags: php

I am trying to make out a code with `preg_replace` 
for example I have this URL:

```
http:\/\/example.com/\fun.php
```

I want to remove `[\]\` tag from the URL not `[/]`
Here is my code that I created

```
$string = 'http:\/\/example.com/\fun.php';
$ans = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$string);
print_r($ans);
```

When I try any word like any alphabet then its working properly only `[\]` creating problem.

Comment: should `/\fun.php` to be `\/fun.php` ?

Comment: Could you please cleanup/rephrase your question. What exactly do you want to replace? ```\``` ? Or ``[`` , `]` and ```\``` ? ``\`` is a special char (the escape char) that must be escaped by another ``\`` so it can work inside the regex.

Comment: Try `'/[\\]/'` or `'/\\/'`. You should escape backslash in strings

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following code -

```
$string = 'http:\/\/example.com/\fun.php';
$ans = stripslashes($string);
print_r($ans);
```